# Make edittext uneditable after 60 characs

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to disable the text entering into edittext after 60 characters.This is the code I have tried to implement,

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "").length() <= 40) {
                    edittext.setKeyListener(variable);
                } else {
                    //edittext.setCursorVisible(false);
                    edittext.setKeyListener(null);

                    Toast.makeText(PersonalChatActivity.this, "60 characs allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    edittext.setKeyListener((KeyListener)edittext.getTag());
            }
        });
```

Also tried to setting cetCoursorVisiblefalse(false) , setEnabled(false) , setFocusable(false) , setFocusableinTouchMode( false).All these work fine.But when I try to clear the text by pressing back button on keyboard,the text ain't clearing.Any suggestions on how to implement this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that a back button or delete button of keyboard?

Comment: @AbhishekDabral back button keyboard..which is used to clear text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
int maxLength = 60;
InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
myEditText.setFilters(fArray);
```

Comment: I should add this in the addTextChangedListener right?

Comment: No, before the listener.

Comment: Its working...but not as expected.After 60 characs,no character should be appended to the entered text.But if I keep typing here,new charcs are being replaced with the old ones.Also in textChanged method i have a toast display that says "Only 60 charcs allowed",that too isn't getting displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (!(s.toString().length() <= 60)) {
                edittext.setText(s.subSequence(0, 60));
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can add the white spaces removal method, i forgot to add

Comment: @AndroidMech any time :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside layout xml, for edittext widget you can set `android:maxLength` property of edittext.

Example:

```
<Edittext 
  android:id="@+id/et_entry"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:maxLength="60"
/>
```

So after 60 characters it will not accept more inputs from user. But if user deletes some characters then again edittext will accept inputs and will accept till length of character is 60.

Comment: @Rajan Raiyaresia yes I could have done that,but my string does not contain white spaces in between so i am replacing white spaces with  replaceAll("\\s","") so the white spaces removed string is actually 60 characs.If i add maxlength property then I am at a disadvantage

Comment: did not get what exactly you are trying to do? from your code i see you are removing all whitespaces and then checking the length is less than or equal to 40. So do you actually want length of the string inputted in edittext should be max 40 without whitespace.not 60? Based on what you have want this can be done using maxlength property.

Comment: I mentioned 40?..I am really sorry..I must have mistakenly written 40 for some testing purposes because 60 was too long .It should be 60.

Comment: I just wanted the text to stop being entered in edittext after 60 characs and even if the user keeps tapping on keyboard he should be shown a message that 60 characs was the limit.

Comment: I m not sure whether you are aware or not. In new Android version there is a property "Show Notification" with checkbox in apps setting page. If user uncheck the checkbox no toast will be displayed. So better solution is below edittext put a label which displays number of characters left and in ontextchange or afterTextChanged method of textwatcher you can update that label. So ones 60 characters are over it will display 0 characters left as it is displaying in comments here in Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is exact solution but Try this:

```
   in xml.
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:maxLength="60"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    >
   <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

  In activity:

   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(editText.getText().length() >= 60){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "60 characs allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
             }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: No..this is half right..how do i disable and enable entering text?..Disable text when 60 characs reached..and enable it again..if user clears some text and again enters some text..

Comment: as it is specified android:maxLength="20" it will never allow to enter text mroe than 20 .... so there is no use of putting an condition of if(editText.getText().length() >= 60) in ontextchanged method.

Comment: sorry it was 60 only for testing I have changed it to 20. anyway thanks for that